# Where does the html code live inside an appex page?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to update html code of the page inside an apex app but cannot find it. Is there a way to see the HTML code of a page in apex app?

Comment: Most of the HTML is generated dynamically at runtime. There is no way to edit it. Any static/custom code must be added through the APEX UI as page or item properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page typically consists of regions. Regions can be various types (eg a report, a map, a data entry form etc).  For many types of region, the majority of the content is generated by APEX itself, hence the term "low code".

But on most of them, you can add static html that appears at the start or end of the region, and there is a region type of "static content" where all of the content is defined by you at design time.  Similarly, there is a region where all of the content comes from a PL/SQL procedure, where you are responsible for providing all the relevant HTML as output from that procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Apex consists of html, css (to make it shiny) and javascript. The default css and javascript are stored in static files (check the page source for that) and the html is stored in the database.
The way the html is applied on a page region is by way of a template. Every component in apex (page, region, report, breadcrumb,button, ...) uses a template and that is just an additional property to check in the builder for that component.

To see all the templates in an app go to Shared Components > User Interface > Templates. To see which templates are referenced in a page check 'Page Shared Components' > Templates (in the left pane of the builder).

It is possible to change templates and even create your own - or you could copy one and modify it to your needs (which is easiest). However, to ensure smoother upgrades it is easier to stick with what is available out of the box.